# How did they know the radius of the earth in ancient times?

Tags: earth, history, geometry

We've all heard how in ancient times they determined that the earth was round, and were able to calculate its radius based on the measured shadows of two separate sticks in the ground at noon.  I am not questioning the math used, but instead the time constant and means of communication between the locations.

Specifically, how would the person monitoring the experiment at stick "A" communicate that it was high noon there so that the person at stick "B" could note direction and length of the shadow at that location?  It's not like they had precision timepieces that in the absence of a means to communicate wirelessly they could synchronize prior to separation.

Might they have been close enough to send a visual signal at the appropriate time?  I presumed more distance might be needed for any measurable difference in the shadows.

Comment: I'm not clear on what aspect of the measurement of the Earth's size you are asking about here.  In particular, Eratosthenes's method for measuring the circumference of the planet does not require any synchronized measurements.

Comment: @Buzz, your simple comment jarred something in me...  My thinking has been hampered by an East/West rotation mentality that had me thinking that noon, defined as the sun's apex, would occur at location A, and later at location B, and that the shadows, (presuming the same latitude) would each be equal at local noon.  Therefore the only way to differentiate would be note shadow difference at the same moment in time.  Not true if there is a North/South split where only local noon matters.  Geez... Even though I got it, thanks for the nudge!

Comment: Eratosthenes is the man you are looking for. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Synchronization of measurements or precision time pieces are *not* required. The *local* time when the measurements were taken is what is relevant.

You are also referring to [Eratosthenes's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes) experiment.

In summary from above link:

*Considering two cities **along the same meridian** and measuring both the distance between them and the difference in angles of the shadows cast by the sun on a vertical rod (a gnomon) **in each city at noon** on the summer solstice. The two cities used were Alexandria and Syene (modern Aswan), and the distance between the cities was measured by professional bematists.*

So you *don't* actually need the measurements to be synchronized. You just need to be at two specific locations (along the *same longitude*) at noon on separate days, then observe the angles cast by the shadows.

You may also be interested in reading about [Al-Biruni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Biruni) who was a Persian mathematician who used *triangulation* to measure the radius of the earth, and did this at about the end of the first millennium 1,000 AD. His calculation of earth's radius $R_E\approx 6339.6\ km$ is approximately within $0.27\%$ error of the known radius.

Comment: Thanks!  If you saw my comment on the question it hit me like a ton of bricks as soon as  Buzz mentioned that time synch wasn't required.  And I'd been hung up on that paradigm for years...

Comment: Ah. Okay. Glad you worked it out and good luck with your studies. Cheers.

Comment: Not really studying, (I'm older...) it's just one of those lingering curiosities I finally got around to asking about.

Comment: Good question all the same. Cheers.

Comment: "Synchronization of measurements or precision time pieces are not required." --> Ok, then how to determine two cities along the _same meridian_?  Enough to know one is north-ish of the other?

Comment: That right. And once you're at each location, you use the fact that it is local noon at each location, then check the angles of the shadows. Cheers.

Comment: Al-Biruni link is broken - needs an i on the end of the URL (and I can't edit it as single-character edits aren't allowed).

Comment: @JackB Thanks for that! Well done indeed. And I just fixed the link, so thanks again. Cheers.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It's fairly rough and ready version of north-ish but the answer is that both towns are on the longest river in the world, which (unusually) happens to flow pretty much South to North.

Comment: "at noon on separate days" - didn't it have to be on the same day?   Otherwise the values could be off since the length of the shadows change from day to day.  It might be worth mentioning the reason they have to be on the same meridian.   I think it is simply because they needed to measure the distance north/south.   Wouldn't any point on the same latitude work?

Answer (score 8):

You can tell local solar noon with a sundial, no communication needed. If the locations are at the same longitude, that time is the same, and the distance between them represents the length of the arc whose angle the shadows measure.