# How did Al-Biruni know the height of a hill?

Tags: earth, history, geometry

I knew of Eratosthenes famous experiment for determining the size of the Earth, but a [recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/702865/how-did-they-know-the-radius-of-the-earth-in-ancient-times/702868#702868) led me to read about another method by Al-Biruni. Like Eratosthenes' method, it required two measurements, but a different two: the height of a hill, and the angle between the local horizontal and the actual horizon at the top of the hill. Wikipedia has [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Biruni#/media/File:Abu_Reyhan_Biruni-Earth_Circumference.svg):

[image: There is a circle with two points on its circumference labeled B and C. The radii to B and C are drawn, and make an angle of about 30° at the center of the circle. A crude drawing of a hill sits outside the circle centered on B, and the peak of the hill is labeled A. There are two straight lines; one is tangent to the circle at C, and the other is in the direction of a tangent at B but placed away from the circle so that it goes through A. The angle between the two lines is labeled α.]

In this diagram, the height of the hill is the length of the line AB. But, how can this height be determined without already knowing the circumference of the earth? Every measurement I can think of made from around the base of the hill would need an additional correction factor that accounts for how much the Earth curved while it was under the hill.

(I tried to Google for this a little bit, but I find it difficult; searches like "how al-biruni height of hill" all return results that talk about how Al-Biruni *used* the height of the hill, not how it was measured. In fact, it goes even farther; most of the results use essentially the *same* two sentences to summarize the experiment...)

Comment: Surely the correction to the height of a hill due to the curvature of the Earth is *tiny* compared to other sources of uncertainty?

Comment: @Andrew Ah! Well, "just get it (a little bit) wrong" was definitely not one of the resolutions I had considered, and does seem like it could be the right one.

Comment: In science, we are *always* at least a little bit wrong -- no measurement is perfect. The trick is to control the sources of uncertainty so they are smaller than the effect you want to measure. I think the diameter of the base of most hills is much, much smaller than the radius of the Earth.

Comment: Standard [geodesy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oarOd3r9-18).

Comment: Did you read https://owlcation.com/stem/How-to-Determin-the-Radius-of-the-Earth-Al-Birunis-Classic-Experiment I think it xplains very good.